# Compare two columns and hightight the specific text

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have data in two columns A and B. Then I want to compare data which is in form of string value in column A with the text value in column B (which is SINGLE WORD text).

For eg:

```
                      Column A                               |  Column B
-------------------------------------------------------------|------------
School Assorted Shape Bead Collection, Assorted Size         |  Assorted
School Assorted Shape Bead Collection                        |  Bamboo
Yasutomo Bamboo Brush Holder, 6 in                           |  Holder
Yasutomo Calligraphy Brushes with Bamboo Vase, Set of 10     |  
                                                             |
```

In column A, 'assorted' is a text which is in column B as well, so in that case I want to highlight the text. If not, then do not highlight. Same for another row, Bamboo is repeating in both the col. A and col. B.

Also it would be great if I will have a message box as popup asking for selecting a range of cells to compare.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim arrKeyword As Variant, arrItem As Variant
    Dim dataRng As Range, keywordRng As Range, rng As Range, cel As Range

    Set dataRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Data Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    Set keywordRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Keyword Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    If Not dataRng Is Nothing And Not keywordRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In dataRng
            For Each arrItem In keywordRng
                If InStr(cel.Value, arrItem) <> 0 Then
                    Debug.Print arrItem & " Exists"
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'change cel property as needed
                End If
            Next arrItem
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

For first input box select your range in `Column A` and for second input box select range in `Column B`. See image for reference.

[image]

**EDIT:**

---

```
Sub Test()
    Dim dataRng As Range, keywordRng As Range, rng As Range, cel As Range

    Set dataRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Data Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    Set keywordRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Keyword Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    If Not dataRng Is Nothing And Not keywordRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In dataRng
            If InStr(cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value) <> 0 Then
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'change cel property as needed
            End If
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the code is working and I got the same result what I was expecting.....Thanks a ton Mrig..

Comment: @VipinSahu - You are welcome.

Comment: Hi Mria, I want to compare cell A1 to B1, A2 to  B2 and An to Bn etc. As per your code it is comparing the whole B column data to col. A string which is wrong. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Mrig-   I want to compare cell A1 to B1, A2 to B2 and An to Bn etc. As per your code it is comparing the whole B column data to col. A string which is wrong. Sorry for the inconvenience. As per the image reference provided above, text  'assorted' is present in both the cells A1 and B1 but keyword 'bamboo' is not present in both cells (A2 does not have bamboo in it) so in this case macro should not highlight.

Comment: @VipinSahu - `Column A` and `Column B` contains the data or its other column?

Comment: @VipinSahu - See edit.

Comment: @Mria- Col. A will be string value and Col. will be having keyword which can be and can't be in col A. But the comparison should be with adjacent cells (A1 to B1)...(A2 to B2).....(An to Bn).

Comment: @VipinSahu - See edit in my answer.

Comment: @Mria- Col. A will be string value and Col.B will be having keyword which can be and can't be in col A. But the comparison should be with adjacent cells (A1 to B1)...(A2 to B2).....(An to Bn). As per the image ref., In cell A1 text 'assorted' is there which is in cell B1 as well. But if u see Bamboo is not there in cell A2 but it is there in cell B2 so in this case do not highlight the cell.

Comment: @VipinSahu - Did you try new code I've added? Image in my answer is for previous code. And its Mrig not Mria.

Comment: @mrig- Thanks for reworking on this macro. Now it looks fine.